# Does anyone else have issues with Azure Batch successfully completing sample tasks on a trial subscription in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I've been trying to get the [Azure batch sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/GettingStarted) to run on my machine for some time now, specifically the [Hello World](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/GettingStarted/01_HelloWorld) example. When the code is ran, it successfully creates the pools, jobs, and tasks on my Batch account. However, the tasks never complete, and remain stuck in the "Active" state. The terminal times out after 10 minutes of waiting, and end the program.

I've looked into this a fair amount, and I'm almost positive this has to do with the Virtual Machine sizes. When looking at the pools on my account after I try running the code, they almost immediately throw an error saying that I've reached my core quota limit.  The VMs that the Hello World example starts you out with are listed in the [settings.json file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/CSharp/GettingStarted/01_HelloWorld/settings.json) as the "standard_d1_v2" size. However, after looking into the resources available for my trial subscription, that VM size isn't listed as one of the three types I have access to.

I've tried changing the reference in the settings.json file, but whenever I do that, the program deletes the job before it can fully run and gives [the following errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRT6t.png)

Is there something I'm missing here? I've watched/followed multiple tutorials on these examples, and none of them mention having to reconfigure their VM sizes. I've looked all over the place and can't seem to find anyone else that has had a similar issue. The only thing close to a resolution I've found people suggesting is to put in a request to increase your core quota, which I am unable to do with a trial subscription.

I did, however, find out that the Hello World example was using the CloudServiceConfiguration class to build the pools, which I learned is deprecated and no longer supported. I'm currently working on replacing all instances of the CloudServiceConfiguration with its replacement, the VirtualMachineConfiguration class.

Any help or feedback/perspective would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) or [Batch Explorer](https://azure.github.io/BatchExplorer/) to view details of each of the objects created by the sample to understand what could have gone wrong.

If your account is reaching core quota limits, then that is exactly the problem. You will need to understand [core quotas in Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-quota-limit#core-quotas) and how they work if in Batch managed mode vs. User subscription. Looking at your Batch account in the Azure Portal will tell you not only the mode but core quotas if in Batch managed mode. You will need to modify the sample to use a VM family that you have core quota.

Completely clean up your Batch account of pools and jobs before rerunning the sample.

If it's something that you believe is an error with the sample code, please [raise an issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/issues) in the respective GitHub repo.